# Why LEFT JOIN increase query time so much?

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and encountered strange problem.

This is the original query I've been using:

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE_TEMP]

INSERT INTO [TABLE_TEMP]
   SELECT H.*, NULL 
   FROM [TABLE_Accounts_History] H
   INNER JOIN [TABLE_For_Filtering] A ON H.[RSIN] = A.[RSIN]
   WHERE
      H.[NUM] = (SELECT TOP 1 [NUM] FROM [TABLE_Accounts_History]
                 WHERE [RSIN] = H.[RSIN] 
                   AND [AccountSys] = H.[AccountSys]
                   AND [Cl_Acc_Typ] = H.[Cl_Acc_Typ]
                   AND [DATE_DEAL] < @dte
                 ORDER BY [DATE_DEAL] DESC)
      AND H.[TYPE_DEAL] <> 'D'
```

Table `TABLE_Accounts_History` consists of **3 200 000** records.

Table `TABLE_For_Filtering` is around **1 500** records.

Insert took me **2m 40s** and inserted **1 600 000** records for further work.

But then I decided to attach a column from pretty small table `TABLE_Additional` (only around **100** recs):

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE_TEMP]

INSERT INTO [TABLE_TEMP]
   SELECT H.*, P.[prof_type]    
   FROM [TABLE_Accounts_History] H
   INNER JOIN [TABLE_For_Filtering] A ON H.[RSIN] = A.[RSIN]
   LEFT JOIN [TABLE_Additional] P ON H.[ACCOUNTSYS] = P.[AccountSys]
   WHERE        H.[NUM] = ( SELECT TOP 1    [NUM]
                        FROM            [TABLE_Accounts_History]
                        WHERE           [RSIN] = H.[RSIN]
                                    AND [AccountSys] = H.[AccountSys]
                                    AND [Cl_Acc_Typ] = H.[Cl_Acc_Typ]
                                    AND [DATE_DEAL] < @dte
                        ORDER BY        [DATE_DEAL] DESC)
        AND H.[TYPE_DEAL] <> 'D'
```

And now it takes ages this query to complete. Why is it so? How such small left join possibly can dump performance? How can I improve it?

**An update:** no luck so far with `LEFT JOIN`. Indexes, no indexes, hinted indexes.. For now I've found a workaround by using my first query and UPDATE after it:

```
UPDATE  [TABLE_TEMP]
SET     [PROF_TYPE] = P1.[prof_type]
FROM    [TABLE_TEMP] A1
LEFT JOIN
        [TABLE_Additional] P1
    ON  A1.[ACCOUNTSYS] = P1.[AccountSys]
```

Takes only 5s and does pretty much the same I've been trying to achieve. Still SQL Server performance is mystery to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'small' left join is actually doing a lot of extra work for you. SQL Server has to go back to TABLE_Additional for each row from your inner join between and TABLE_Accounts_History and TABLE_For_Filtering. You can help SQL Server a few ways to speed this up by trying some indexing. You could:

1) Ensure TABLE_Accounts_History has an index on the Foreign Key H.[ACCOUNTSYS]

2) If you think that TABLE_Additional will always be accessed by the AccountSys, i.e. you will be requesting AccountSys in ordered groups, you could create a Clustered Index on TABLE_Additional.AccountSys. (in orther words physically order the table on disk in order of AccountSys)

3) You could also ensure there is a foreign key index on TABLE_Accounts_History.

Comment: I've been doing it before, actually by using hint like FROM  TABLE_Accounts_History H WITH (INDEX(accounts_h_search1)). No success. Same thing with another table. And the smaller table actually has clustered index.

Comment: I would steer clear of table hints unless you really are at an advanced stage. SQL Server has a box called the Optimiser which decides how best to run your query. Manual hints can sometimes be counter productive if you don't know where the real issue is. If you view the Execution plan for the query in Query Analyser you should see where the highest cost is. Feel free to attach a picture of it here and I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Well, execution plan is pretty long (two screens horizontally) so no image, sorry, but left join itself has cost of 0%. Clustered Index Scan on TABLE_Accounts_History takes 11% and NonClustered Index Scan on same table is 87%. Both far before it comes to left join. The ACTUAL exec plan should be different, but I never was patient enough for this query to finish.

Comment: can you take a screenshot of the thing that is taking 87% with the mouse hovered over it ? That's the key.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to post images, here is a link. Sorry in case you don't understand language, don't have English environment [link](http://s8.postimg.org/a6ka3tvbp/nci.png)

Comment: The image shows a non clustered index seek for 2884950 rows if my Cyrillic is right. Which basically means SQL server is having to do a lot of work to do the join  and Get DateDeal and Num. By rewriting the query above you have avoided the need to do this! Well done for getting round the problem on your own steam.

Answer (score 0):

`left outer join` selects all rows from left table. In Your case your left table has **3 200 000** this much rows and then comparing with each record to your right table. One solution is to use `Indexes` which will reduce retrieval time.

Comment: I'm using them, actually. But this performance drop survives them somehow.